# Setting up the Android emulator with a larger screen aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-emulator

In March 2017, an [announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) was made that two Android devices — the Samsung Galaxy S8 and the LG G6 — were being introduced with new, longer, screen aspect ratios of 18:9 and 18.5:9.

According to the announcement, legacy apps with no `android.max_aspect` or `android.resizeableActivity` value in their manifest would take on a maximum aspect ratio of 1.86 (roughly 16:9) by default. The announcement shows an image of such an app running on one of the new device screens with its content "letterboxed" in the display with black bars shown along the top and bottom of the screen.

How can I set up the Android emulator to display one of the new, longer 18:9 screens? Manually setting the emulator screen resolution doesn’t show the letterboxed effect.

Comment: This is a big change that will affect all apps. Google is doing a pretty poor job of providing a clear way to test with these large aspect ratios.

Comment: Correction: this should _not_ affect many apps. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 8):

Try these steps:

- In Android Studio, open AVD Manager
- Create Virtual Device

  - New Hardware Profile
  - Set name: "18:9 aspect ratio screen"
  - Set resolution: 1080 x 2160
  - Finish
- Select "18:9 aspect ratio screen"
- Next
- Select system image Nougat (API Level 25)
- Next
- AVD Name: "25 N.1 18x9 aspect ratio screen" [starting AVD names with the API level gets the list sorted by that]
- Finish

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer per se, but I did find some helpful information in the docs.

First, read this note about `android.max_aspect` from the [original announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html):

> Note: if you don't set a value, **and `android:resizeableActivity` is *not* true**, then the maximum aspect ratio defaults to 1.86 (roughly 16:9) and your app will *not* take advantage of the extra screen space.

Now [see these docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#MaxAspectRatio):

> You do not need to set a maximum aspect ratio if an activity's `android:resizeableActivity` attribute is set to true. **If your app targets API level 24 or higher, this attribute defaults to true.**

This means the "letter-boxing" issue will only happen if *both* of these conditions are *true*:

1. The device has a large aspect ratio (> 1.86:1 or 16:9), and,
2. The app targets API 23 or below

So I suspect the situation is not too bad - not many apps will be affected.